# How do I select multiple values in the same column?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select multiple values in a single column. Basically I want the query to select all those under column `family` with values `Software_1Y`,`XI_1Y` and `P1_1Y`

I am running this query :

```
SELECT `salesorder`
    ,`masterproduct`
    ,`family`
    ,`birthstamp`
    ,`duedate`
    ,COUNT(*) AS `total`
FROM `report`
WHERE `birthstamp` BETWEEN '$startDT'
        AND '$endDT'
    AND `family` = 'Software_1Y'
    AND `family = 'XI_1Y'
    AND `family` = 'PI_1Y'
GROUP BY `salesorder`
    ,`masterproduct`
    ,`family`
    ,`duedate`;
```

My query returns no rows but is I search each family one by one, I have values.

What is wrong with my query?

Also, my purpose is to get all the rows whose `family` values are `Software_1Y`, `XI_1Y` and `PI_1Y`.

Comment: Use `IN` or change to `\`family\` = 'Software_1Y' OR \`family\` = 'XI_1Y' OR \`family\` = 'PI_1Y'`

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but if I use `OR` then I only get a Single row right? My purpose is to get all those rows with those `family` values.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

How about using IN instead

```
SELECT  `salesorder`,
        `masterproduct`,
        `family`,
        `birthstamp`,
        `duedate`, 
        COUNT( * ) AS `total` 
FROM    `report` 
WHERE   `birthstamp` BETWEEN '$startDT' AND '$endDT' 
AND     `family` IN ('Software_1Y','XI_1Y','PI_1Y')
GROUP BY    `salesorder`,
            `masterproduct`,
            `family`,
            `duedate`;
```

The reason why no values are returned, is because of this section

```
AND `family` = 'Software_1Y' 
AND `family = 'XI_1Y' 
AND `family` = 'PI_1Y'
```

`family` cannot be all 3 values at once, but it might be 1 of the 3 values.

That is why you would use IN.

Another way to look at it would be to use OR, but that gets really long winded.

Comment: That means there was an error in your SQL. Don't you check for an error from `mysql_query`? The error message should tell you where your mistake was.

Comment: This is by far the best explanation on this type of queries. Thanks astander

Answer (score 1):

```
$query="   SELECT `salesorder`,`masterproduct`,`family`,`birthstamp`,`duedate`, COUNT( * ) AS `total` FROM `report` 
    WHERE `birthstamp` BETWEEN '$startDT' AND '$endDT' 
           AND (`family` = 'Software_1Y' 
           OR `family` = 'XI_1Y' 
           OR `family` = 'PI_1Y') 
    GROUP BY `salesorder`,`masterproduct`,`family`,`duedate` ";
```

It must be due to AND instead of OR while querying FAMILY column.

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
//Operation you want to perform
}
```

@jude: It seems you are directly passing the query which is of type string directly as a parameter to mysql_fetch_array, which is wrong. Instead follow the above approach...

Comment: You would probably want to put some brackets around the ORs... AND (`family` = 'Software_1Y' OR `family = 'XI_1Y' OR `family` = 'PI_1Y')

Comment: @astander: Yeah... it came to my mind as well. But then I thought will it really affect the condition in this particular case?

Comment: YEs, it definitely would, as you have it the order of the operators would be ('$startDT' AND '$endDT' AND `family` = 'Software_1Y') OR `family` = 'XI_1Y' OR `family` = 'PI_1Y'