# MYSQL - Selecting 2 values in same Colum

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get some products from my database where is has number 1 and 2

```
"SELECT * FROM dagenshug_product WHERE stock_quantity > '0' AND product_in_sale = '1' AND category_sex = '1' AND category_sex = '2' AND category_id = '".$req_category_id."' ORDER BY id DESC");
```

As you can see i am choosing category_sex twice, but is only returning ths the values from the first one, (alle with 1)

How do i make it take both? ;)

Thanks for your help

Comment: you can here for more infomation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594343/how-do-i-select-multiple-values-in-the-same-column

Comment: I think rather than use "AND" you should use "OR" on the category

Comment: Your logic is flawed. You looking for rows where sex is **either** 1 **or** 2. Because a row can't have **both** 1 **and** 2 at the same time. so `AND (category_sex = '1' OR category_sex = '2')`. Or better yet, `category_sex IN ('1','2')`.

Comment: @LiverpoolCoder Been there only returning the first one ... in this case.. all with 1 :)

Comment: @ThanhTùng Have tryied that, but i returns nothing ..

Comment: @hlfrmn Thanks my friend.. dont know why, but when i tryed category_sex IN ('1','2') this before, i didn't work, but it do now :O

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this:

```
"SELECT * FROM dagenshug_product 
WHERE 
stock_quantity > 0 AND product_in_sale = '1' AND category_sex IN('1', '2') AND category_id = '".$req_category_id."' ORDER BY id DESC");
```

`category_sex = '1' AND category_sex = '2'` Doesn't makes sense because it  means that value for this column, for same row, should be '1' and '2' same time. this is impossible.

Also not use expressions like this: `stock_quantity > '0'`. This is math comparison, so you can use directly numeric values: `stock_quantity > 0`

Answer (score 1):

```
"SELECT * FROM dagenshug_product WHERE stock_quantity > '0' AND product_in_sale = '1' AND (category_sex = '1' OR category_sex = '2') AND category_id = '".$req_category_id."' ORDER BY id DESC");
```

Try this